# Spring 3.0 : How redirect to same page

Tags: spring-mvc

In Spring MVC, I have a search form. If user submit search form, result should show in same page. 
It is redirecting to same page But I'm not getting attributes in JSP from controller.

**qSearch.jsp**

```
<form:form name="quickSearchForm" id="searchFormId" method="POST" action="./searchQuick.html" modelAttribute="searchForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Change/Defect ID</th><td><form:input type="text" name="identifier" path="identifier"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div class="icons">
                <span><button style="left:0px" type="reset" name="clear" style="border-radius: 25px;">CLEAR</button></span>
                <span><button style="right:0px" type="submit" name="submit" style="border-radius: 25px;" >SEARCH</button></span>
            </div>
        </form:form>

                    <hr>
            <div>
                <c:if test="${empty SEARCH_RESULTS_KEY}">
                <table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="1" class="showResults">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="7">No Results found</td>
                        </tr>
                </table>        
                    </c:if>
            <c:if test="${! empty SEARCH_RESULTS_KEY}">
                <table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="1" class="showResults">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="7">Result found</td>
                        </tr>
                </table> 
           </c:if>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/qSearch", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
public String getQuickSearchmodel(Model model) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to search tool\n");
    ArchivalIssue archivalIssue=new ArchivalIssue();
    model.addAttribute("searchForm", archivalIssue);
    return "quickSearchPage";   
 }

@RequestMapping(value = "/searchQuick", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
public ModelAndView getAllArchivalIssues(HttpServletRequest request){

    String identifier = request.getParameter("identifier"); 
    List<ArchivalIssue> archivalIssue = archivalIssueService.getAllArchivalIssue(identifier);

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("redirect:/qSearch");                           //Add model to display results  
        mav.addObject("SEARCH_RESULTS_KEY", archivalIssue);                         //Add result object to model
        return mav; 

}
```

please someone help me, how to get result in JSP. I'm always getting no result found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not redirect in this case. Because redirect will create new GET request to server. The `quickSearchPage` and `getAllArchivalIssues` should return same view

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchQuick", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
public ModelAndView getAllArchivalIssues(HttpServletRequest request){

    String identifier = request.getParameter("identifier"); 
    List<ArchivalIssue> archivalIssue = archivalIssueService.getAllArchivalIssue(identifier);

    //return quickSearchPage, so that the client can render the list archivalIssue
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("quickSearchPage");                          

    mav.addObject("SEARCH_RESULTS_KEY", archivalIssue); //Add result object to model
    return mav; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply. I tried this. I'm able to redirect to same page but I'm not getting value of attribute "archivalIssue" in JSP.

Answer (score 0):

When the return value contains redirect: prefix, The rest of the view name will be treated as the redirect URL. And the browser will send a new request to this redirect URL. So the  handler method mapped to this URL will be executed.

just return the same page as response with model attributes.

Are you using JSTL is there any changes required

```
${empty param.SEARCH_RESULTS_KEY}
```

Comment: I tried. But unable to get any attributes from controller.

Comment: I am not sure about the last edit because how you rendering using JSTL?